# How can I save Game state to JSON

Tags: c#

I am building a console application game (Connect 4) using C#. How can I save the current game state to JSON and load the game later? I also want to be able to record the current active player and resume the game from there.

My game engine code:

```
using System;

namespace GameEngine
{
    public class Game
    {
        private CellState[,] Board { get; set; }

        public int Width { get; set; }

        public int Height { get; set; }

        private bool _player0Move = true;

        public Game(int height, int width)
        {
            if (width < 4 || height < 4)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Board has to be 4x4 at least");
            }

            Height = height;
            Width = width;
            Board = new CellState[height,width];
        }

        public Game(GameSettings settings)
        {
            if (settings.BoardWidth < 4 || settings.BoardHeight < 4)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Board has to be 4x4 at least");
            }

            Height = settings.BoardHeight;
            Width = settings.BoardWidth;
            Board = new CellState[Height,Width];

        }

        public CellState[,] BoardCopy()
        {
            var result = new CellState[Height, Width];

            Array.Copy(Board, result, Board.Length);

            return result;
        }

        public string Move(int y, int x)
        {

            if (Board[y, x] != CellState.Empty)
            {
                return "copy";
            }

            Board[y, x] = _player0Move ? CellState.X : CellState.O;
            _player0Move = !_player0Move;

            return "Ok";
        }


    }
}
```

My CellState enum:

```
using System;

namespace GameEngine
{
    public enum CellState
    {
        Empty,
        O,
        X
    }
}
```

I have been struggling with this. I am using the newton JSON framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the basic principles below:

To **load** the state:

```
var settingsPath = @"C:\temp\settings.json";
var json = File.ReadAllText(settingsPath);
game.Board = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CellState>(json);
```

To **save** the state:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(game.Board);
var settingsPath = @"C:\temp\settings.json";
File.WriteAllText(settingsPath , json);
```

The error handlings are omitted from these snippet for your assignment.